# How to SQLite convert string '123[45]/67[8]/9[10]' to '123/67/9'

Tags: sql, sqlite

#### DDL&DML

```sql
create table T (value Text);
insert into T (value) values ('123[45]/67[8]/9[10]'),('333[11]/77[222]/55[3]');
```

#### what i expected

```
value
123/67/9
333/77/55
```

Online test link : [SQLite 3.8 | db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=e7d3e1d00339da4ea434fe5220a3817f)

#### what i have tried

I tried to use trim or replace but it's not work.

Comment: Do you have sqlite `icu_replace` extension installed? Without regexes, this will be tedious.

Comment: @GMB no,it's on the azure windows service app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can think to do this uses a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select NULL as chr, value as rest, 0 as in_braces, '' as output, value, 0 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select substr(rest, 1, 1),
             substr(rest, 2),
             (case when rest like '[%' then 1
                   when rest like ']%' then 0
                   else in_braces
             end) as in_braces,
             (case when in_braces or rest like '[%' then output
                   else output || substr(rest, 1, 1)
              end),
             value, lev + 1
      from cte
      where rest <> ''
     )
select cte.value, cte.output
from cte join
     (select value, max(lev) as max_lev
      from cte
      group by value
     ) m
     on cte.value = m.value and cte.lev = m.max_lev;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=8af661a9bcf4d61d0d7dbacdb1185bf1) is a db<>fiddle.